# How to count number of entries in a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file:
**10
List of ARFCNs = 987 988 989 991 992 993 995 999 1000 1004 1008 1009 1010 1011 1012 1018 1019 1020 1023**
I want a code such that it returns the number of values in the list i.e. 19 in this case.
Furthermore, I need to use this number of entries such that if the answer is either 0 or more than 1, the output prints a textline. But if the numbe ris exactly 1, then another statement is printed.
I know its a very basic question but I cant find any specific solution.
I tried using len, but im not sure as to what should be the delimiter. Putting space as a delimiter gives a faulty answer. I want an exception to the code where entries after the **=** sign are counted and then processed in an if/else loop probably.

Comment: Share the code you attempted, output, and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code:

```
with open('problem.txt','r') as myfile:
    file_str = myfile.read()
my_list = [] ##initializing a list
for word in string.split('=')[1].split(' '): ##using split function to split, the list.this splits the value in index specified and return the value.
 ## storing the updated list
    my_list.append(word)
for var in my_list:
    if var == '':
        my_list.remove(var)
if len(my_list) == 0 :
    print(f'the number of entries are zero')
else:
    print(f'the number of entries are {len(my_list)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```py
numbers = data.split("=")[1].split(" ")
for value in numbers:
    if value == "":
        numbers.remove(value)
count = len(numbers)
```

Here data the the whole string tha you are reading from text file.
This will return the number counts and you can use it further.